# How to get loop to start on a mouse click in python

Tags: python, click, mouse

I am struggling to find a way to get my program to change the image to grayscale after the user clicks on the original image. The curly brackets are where I believe my problem is.

```
import image

img = image.Image("nature.jpg")
win = image.ImageWin(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
img.draw(win)
img.setDelay(1,15)

if {}:
    for row in range(img.getHeight()):
        for col in range(img.getWidth()):
            p = img.getPixel(col, row)

        aver = (p.getRed() + p.getGreen() + p.getBlue())/3

        newred = aver
        newgreen = aver
        newblue = aver

        newpixel = image.Pixel(newred, newgreen, newblue)

        img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)

img.draw(win)
```

Comment: I tried inputing mouse_click() but it sayed it was an unidentified name.

Comment: I think `image` library cannot handle this task. search for a library with mouse input support. Pygame for example.